# How can I change date format?

Tags: php, date

In my PHP file, date is in this format: "2012-10-09 00:00:00"; I need to show it as "October 9" or  "Oct 9" (excluding the year).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any efforts given ? Have you tried or search anything ?

Comment: its quite easy `echo date("M d", strtotime($from))`

Comment: Thank you kiamlaluno, Rikesh, webGautam

Comment: Hi Yasmin, welcome. One of the things we like here is if question-askers search the web before asking questions - it helps limit the load here, but also helps programmers themselves, as it makes them more self-sufficient. Here, I would have searched for "PHP format date", and I'm sure one of the results would have helped `:-)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo date("M, d", strtotime($from));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$from= "2012-10-09 00:00:00"
echo date('F n Y, strtotime($from)); // n-day, F- full month name, Y-Year 
?>
```

Please check this link for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
You can skip 'Y' above to remove year from output.

Comment: $from= "2012-10-09 00:00:00";
echo date('M j', strtotime($from));

// result Oct 9